# with @SpringBootTest (or @WebfluxTest), the errors attribute disappears

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, response, spring-webflux, hibernate-validator

I made very simple controller like below.

```
@PostMapping("/books")
public void create(@Valid @RequestBody BookPayload bookPayload) {
    
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class BookPayload {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String author;
}
```

When I call this api without name. It responses like below.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-03-26T14:06:43.564+00:00",
  "path": "/books",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "requestId": "654248ee-5",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotBlank.bookPayload.name",
        "NotBlank.name",
        "NotBlank.java.lang.String",
        "NotBlank"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "bookPayload.name",
            "name"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "name",
          "code": "name"
        }
      ],
      ... omit ...
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see errors attribute in the response body.
But If I test this api with @SpringBootTest or @WebfluxTest, There is no errors attribute.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CommonErrorResponseTest {
    private final WebClient web;

    public CommonErrorResponseTest(@LocalServerPort Integer port) {
        web = WebClient.create("http://localhost:" + port);
    }

    @Test
    void _400_badRequest_violation() {
        BookPayload bookPayload = new BookPayload();
        bookPayload.setAuthor("John");
        Mono<String> stringMono = web.post().uri("/books")
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .bodyValue(bookPayload)
            .exchangeToMono(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class));

        String body = stringMono.block();
        log.info("body: {}", body);
    }
}
```

console

```
body: {"timestamp":"2022-03-26T14:19:21.981+00:00","path":"/books","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","requestId":"68df2a79-1"}
```

I'd like to know why I'm getting different results.

Comment: In your test, you're having this: `bookPayload.setName("John");`, and according to what you're testing with "When I call this api without name. It responses like below.", that is a difference.

Comment: sorry Roar S. I edit my source code.

Comment: @RoarS. Thank you for your interest.
The key point is that the errors attribute is not in the response.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot’s Devtools?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes. Does it have a side effect? I've tried removing it, but it's the same. You can check out the code from https://github.com/louishuh/practice-error-response 
thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot’s DevTools enables the inclusion of binding errors in the error response to ease problem solving during development. You can configure the same behaviour in your tests by setting `server.error.include-binding-errors` to always.

You can see a complete list of the properties that DevTools sets [in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.5/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.property-defaults).

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to you @AndyWilkinson